# remove li element when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am dynamically able to add a new `li` element on checked event of a checkbox. However I am not able to remove the same on the `unchecked` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var value;

    $(".tmCheckbox").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            value = $(this).val();
            $('.ul_sec').append($('<li>', {
                text: value
            }));
        } else {
            // $(this).parent().remove();
        }

    });
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<h3>MY SELECTION </h3>
<ul class="ul_sec" style="display: block;">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="">Random Text 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="">Random Text 2</li>

</ul>

<h3>FILTER</h3>
<ul style="display: block;">
    <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 1">Random Text 1</li>
    <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 2">Random Text 2</li>
    <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 3">Random Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: show you html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out `li` element based on text content using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and remove it using [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

```
var $this = this;
$('.ul_sec li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == $this.value;
}).remove();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var value;

  $(".tmCheckbox").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.ul_sec').append($('<li>', {
        html: this.outerHTML + value
      }));
    } else {
      $('.ul_sec li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == value;
      }).remove();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>MY SELECTION </h3>
<ul class="ul_sec" style="display: block;">
</ul>

<h3>FILTER</h3>
<ul style="display: block;">
  <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 1">Random Text 1</li>
  <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 2">Random Text 2</li>
  <li><input class="tmCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Random Text 3">Random Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will this be in the else statement

Comment: i also want to add the checkbox along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `remove()` to the target where it is appended

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var value;

    $(".tmCheckbox").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            value = $(this).val();
            $('.ul_sec').append($('<li>', {
                text: value
            }));
        } else {
             $('.ul_sec li').last().remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This removes _all_ `<li>` elements from the list

Comment: Need to use `li:last`, specify an `id` or similar to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById("yourid").remove();` giving an id to the `<li>` you just added.